# What would be the expression to get the elements of the density matrix in the energy representation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, density-operator

Given a quantum system that is subject to a Hamiltonian *H* (*H* is no time dependent) and its state (of the quantum system) at time *t* is $|\psi(t)\rangle$. What would be the elements of the matrix of the corresponding density operator as an explicit function of time, in the energy representation? I've done this,

Eigenstates of the energy are, ${H|m\rangle = E_m|m\rangle}$.

Our state is, $|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt/\hslash}|\psi(0)\rangle$. But $|\psi(0)\rangle$ can be represented as a linear combination of eigenstates of the energy $|\psi(0)\rangle = \sum\limits_{m} E_m |m\rangle$ so,

$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum\limits_{m} e^{-iHt/\hslash} E_m |m\rangle$$

On the other hand, density matrix is, $\rho = \sum\limits_{i} {(P_i) |\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i|}$ but if it is a pure state $\rho = |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$

Now, if we want to get the elements of $\rho$ in the energy representation,

$$
\rho_{nm} = \langle n|\rho |m\rangle = \langle n| ({|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|}) |m\rangle
$$

$$
\rho_{nm} = \langle n|\rho |m\rangle = \langle n|({e^{-iHt/\hslash} |\psi(0)\rangle \langle \psi(0)| e^{iHt/\hslash}})|m\rangle
$$

$$
\rho_{nm} = \langle n|\rho |m\rangle = \langle n|({\sum\limits_{m{'}} e^{-iHt/\hslash} E_{m{'}} |m{'}\rangle \sum\limits_{n{'}} \langle n{'}| e^{iHt/\hslash} E_{n{'}}})|m\rangle
$$

$$
\rho_{nm} = \langle n|\rho |m\rangle = \langle n|({\sum\limits_{m{'}} e^{-iE_{m{'}}t/\hslash} E_{m{'}} |m{'}\rangle \sum\limits_{n{'}} \langle n{'}| e^{iE_{n{'}}t/\hslash} E_{n{'}}})|m\rangle
$$

$$
\rho_{nm} = \langle n|\rho |m\rangle = \sum\limits_{m{'} n{'}} \langle n|({e^{-iE_{m{'}}t/\hslash} |\psi(0)\rangle \langle \psi(0)|  e^{iE_{n{'}}t/\hslash}})|m\rangle
$$

$$
\rho_{nm} = \langle n|\rho |m\rangle = \sum\limits_{m{'} n{'}} {e^{-i(E_{m{'}}-E_{n{'}})t/\hslash}} \langle n| (|\psi(0)\rangle \langle \psi(0)|)|m\rangle
$$

This is my final expression but I'm not sure if this is correct, I am relatively new to these topics.

I really appreciate opinions and corrections, thank you for your time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.